# $_COOKIE не видит ключ

Tags: php, html

Выдает ошибку  (Warning: Undefined array key "user")

```
<body>
    <div class="container mt-4">
        <?php if(count($_COOKIE['user']) == ''):?> #В этом месте не может определить ключ
         /*HTML-код*/

        <?php else:?>
            <p><br>Привет <?=$_COOKIE['user']?>!</p> #А тут проблем нет
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: ну когда в куке нет ничего, что, по-вашему, должно быть?

Comment: Ну по моему видению он должен исполнить Html-код, это и есть суть условия если в куке ничего нет он должен вывести форму авторизации в моем случае

Comment: ну исполнить-то он его исполнит.....но вопрос-то ваш в другом заключался, не так ли? так что это чисто логический вопрос: если ключа нет, то что вы ожидаете от интерпретатора, который ожидает ключ в массиве?

Comment: Я думал что ключи по дефолту содержаться, ну теперь понятно, тогда подскажите как правильно поставить условие?

Comment: проверить на наличие ключа можно через array_key_exists..... можно через isset, но если ключ всё же будет и он будет null - то isset не сработает....поэтому проще первый вариант.

Comment: Сработало, спасибо! Можете добавить как ответ, я отмечу, если надо....

Answer (score 2):

Вы сравниваете результат функции count, возвращаемое значение которой имеет тип int со строкой. Если в $_COOKIE['user'] ничего нет, в if сразу передаётся false. Проверьте:

```
if($_COOKIE['user']) {
    echo('cookie here');
}else {
    echo('no cookies');
}
```

Вам должно подойти:

```
<?php if(!$_COOKIE['user']) { ?>
    /*HTML-код*/
<?php } else { ?>
    <p><br>Привет <?php echo($_COOKIE['user']) ?>!</p>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Точно, спасибо за замечание про сравнение инта со стрингом, но проблема не решена, он все еще не видит ключ. Добавлю что он исполняет код и выводит форму, но пишет сверху про ошибку